# spring boot tomcat external properties file

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have spring boot based war file deployed in tomcat. I am not able to use external application properties file. I am using following to provide the path of external properties file

```
X:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin>startup.bat --Dspring.config.location=X:\conf\application.properties
```

I have also tried it with qoutes

```
X:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin>startup.bat "--Dspring.config.location=X:\conf\application.properties"
```

These properties are not working and spring is reading properties file that are bundled inside the war file. Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Using global parameters with an external Tomcat is awkward, because you could theoretically have multiple applications running on it. I have answered a similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106579/external-configuration-for-spring-boot-application/29122037#29122037 Posted as a comment here, because it's not a direct answer to your question, but you might consider going down this route instead

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:X:/conf/application.properties
```

You have to add `file:` if you need a file outside of classpath

Comment: it is not working. Application is still reading properties files enclosed in war file

Comment: can you edit
CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh

and add

export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dspring.config.location=file:X:/conf/application.properties"

Comment: the setenv.bat works. I have added a setenv.bat file in my TOMCAT_HOME/bin folder and with set spring.config.location code and its was working but some how it is not the requirement