# Running multiple spring boot web app on tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy multiple spring boot web app on tomcat. All have the same application.properties.How can I split the configuration files for different app running on tomcat.

Comment: I've had the same issue and have posted an answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106579/external-configuration-for-spring-boot-application/29122037#29122037).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't require an external Tomcat, because it contains its own embedded Tomcat. So you can run all of your application in it's own Tomcat on the same machine. All you have to do is to define different ports for your applications via `server.port` property.

Comment: We can't run them independently it needs to integrated with other services. We have to deploy those into our existing tomcats.

Comment: Why not following microservice approach and calling them by thier endpoints?